# Save json response as a constant

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm working with ReactJS, and I'm trying to save a json array as a 'const'. Something like this:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    this.setState({
      data: json
    });  
  });
```

But I don't want to save it in the state, because the array will not change.

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Save it in a variable or localstorage

```
let dataJson = {};
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    dataJson = json
  });
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you shouldn't be able to re-assign "dataJson" as it's declared as a const.

Comment: Isn't he trying to save it in a constant

Comment: further we can improve by optimizing arrow function into just one line

let dataJson = {};
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => dataJson = json);

Answer (score 2):

```
let data;

fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
     data = json
  });
```

Comment: I did it, and 'data' appears as 'undefined'. It's weird, if I used 'setState' it works perfectly.